# I can't show data between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

As I mentioned in the title, I want to show **the data between two dates** in the database.

Here is my table:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xU7W.png)

I just want to show the lines between these two dates.

Briefly, the formula will be as follows: `departure date ≤ now < arrival date`

I've tried many things over the past few days but without success.

If there's an easy way around this, can you also tell me what I should do to show before and after these two dates?Thanks from now..

I tried BETWEEN-INTERVAL

```
BETWEEN kalkis_tarih - INTERVAL varis_tarih
```

I tried using if() and i tried many things i found on the internet.

I guess there is a simple solution but I couldn't find it :/

my code:

```
<?php
        foreach (cok("SELECT * FROM seferler INNER JOIN crew ON crew.crew_id=seferler.kaptan_id INNER JOIN filo ON filo.filo_id=seferler.arac_id INNER JOIN duraklar ON duraklar.id=seferler.kalkis AND seferler.varis ORDER BY kalkis_tarih LIMIT 20") as $key => $sefer): ?>
          <tr>
              <th scope="row text-center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= date_format(date_create($sefer['kalkis_tarih']),"d/m/y") ?><br><?= date_format(date_create($sefer['kalkis_tarih']),"h:i") ?> - <?= date_format(date_create($sefer['varis_tarih']),"h:i") ?></th>
              <td><?php foreach(cok("SELECT durak FROM duraklar WHERE id={$sefer['kalkis']}") as $key => $kalkis): ?><?= $kalkis['durak'] ?><?php endforeach ?> | <?= date_format(date_create($sefer['kalkis_tarih']),"d/m - h:i") ?> </td>
              <td><?php foreach(cok("SELECT durak FROM duraklar WHERE id={$sefer['varis']}") as $key => $varis): ?><?= $varis['durak'] ?><?php endforeach ?> | <?= date_format(date_create($sefer['varis_tarih']),"d/m - h:i") ?></td>
              <td><?= $sefer['crew_name'] ?></td>
              <td><?= $sefer['filo_name'] ?></td>
              <td><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i></td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want those rows from the database where the departure date/time is equal or smaller than the current date/time, and the arrival date/time is bigger than the current date/time.

Basically those rows that are "in transit". This is almost as simple as you wrote it:

```
departure <= NOW() AND arrival > NOW()
```

or

```
kalkis_tarih <= NOW() AND varis_tarih > NOW()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
The code you gave solved my problem in general. I am getting error (>=) in this code. It's not much of a problem, I can use it the way it is now:  departure < NOW() AND arrival > NOW()

Comment: @emretarhan Ah, yes, sorry, my fault. It's `<=` instead of `=<`. I'll change the answer.